# My input sometimes takes multiple times for it to go in the if statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a basic rock, paper, scissors game. When I input either rock, paper, or scissors, I sometimes have to enter the same thing multiple times for it to continue to the if statements. See code below:

```
# Rock, Paper, Scissors
player_total = 0
computer_total = 0


def get_computer_hand():
    choice = randint(1, 3)
    if choice == 1:
        return "scissors"
    elif choice == 2:
        return "paper"
    else:
        return "rock"


def ask_user():
    global player_total
    global computer_total
    player = input("Enter your hand (stop to stop): ")
    if player == "stop":
        print("Computer had ", computer_total, "points, you had ", player_total, " points.")
        exit(0)
    computer = get_computer_hand()
    if player == "rock":
        if computer == "paper":
            return "win"
        elif computer == "scissors":
            return "lose"
        else:
            return "tie"
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "paper":
            return "tie"
        elif computer == "scissors":
            return "lose"
        else:
            return "win"
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "scissors":
            return "tie"
        elif computer == "paper":
            return "win"
        else:
            return "lose"


def count_winner():
    global player_total
    global computer_total
    player_total = 0
    computer_total = 0
    while True:
        outcome = ask_user()
        if outcome == "win":
            print("You won that one.")
            player_total += 1
        elif outcome == "lose":
            print("Computer won that one.")
            computer_total += 1


count_winner()
```

I expect it to work the first time and to continue as usual, but I can't seem to figure out why it just asks "Enter your hand (stop to stop): " instead sometimes when I enter either rock, paper, or scissors.

Comment: This is happening when `outcome == "tie"`, as you have no output case for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because there is a tie happening between the computer and the user. This could be fixed by adding the end with the code of

`else outcome == "tie":
            print("You have tied with the Computer!")
            computer_total += 1
            player_total += 1`

This would add a point to both sides and if you don't want that just delete the last two lines of my code

Comment: You need `elif`, not `else`.

Comment: Yikes! Looks like I overlooked this by mistake. My program works now, thanks for the help!